# If I repartition by column name does spark understand that it is repartitioned by that column when it is read back

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql-repartition

I have a requirement, where I have a huge dataset of over 2 Trillion records. This comes as a result of some join. And post this join, I need to aggregate on a column ('id' column) and get a list of distinct names (collect_set('name')).

1. Now, while saving the join result in step1, if I re-partition it on 'id' field, will I get any benefit?
   i.e. joined_df.repartition('id').write.parquet(path)
2. If I read the above repartitioned df, will spark understand that it is already repartitioned on id field, so that when I group by id, performance is hugely improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `id` column is unique, then you just add a huge overhead to partition by this column, since each partition will contain one record, so assuming this is not the case!

Calling `repartition('id')` will create partitions based on the `id` column, but it will not influence Spark that the data is already partitioned when reading back.

If the data of each `id` can fit in one partition, I'd say you could try to:

- Repartition by column and number of partitions 1, to make sure each `id` is in one partition only.
- Read the saved data and since each partition contains the data of one `id`(logically) you can avoid the extra group by and map the partitions directly.

Example:

```py
joined_df.repartition(1, 'id').write.parquet(path)
...
spark.read.parquet(path).rdd.mappartitions(FUN).toDF([id, ...])
```